# How can I get the href of all images on a page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-traversal

Is it possible for me to get the href of all images on a page using JavaScript? This code gives me the src for those images, but I want to return the href for them.

```
function checkimages() {
     var images = document.images;
     for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++){
        var img =images[i].src;
       alert(img);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @Kyle points out, an `img` does not have an `href` attribute, they only have `src`. Just guessing, but you might have a link (`a`) around your images, and its `href` stores the path to the big image (in case `img` is a thumbnail).

In this situation, you could use:

```
function checkImages() {
     var images = document.images;
     for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
        if (images[i].parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
           console.log(images[i].parentNode.href);
        }
     }
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uK4Jf/)

Comment: I didn't think of that, but that's a very good possibility. +1

Answer (score 3):

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("IMG");
for (var i=0, len=a.length; i<len; i++)
  alert (a[i].src);
```

Answer (score 2):

Images don't have an `href` attribute, that applies only to anchors (`a`).

Comment: I know, and he is already doing that with the code he provided. I had to answer it because I couldn't just add a comment at the time.

Comment: then how return attribute anchor with images?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for src attribute

```
function checkimages() {
     var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
     for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++){
        var img =images[i].getAttribute('src');
       alert(img);
     }
}
```